# Is there an interactive table widget for Shiny for python that calls back selected rows?

Tags: python, ipywidgets, py-shiny

I'm using reactable, Datatable or rhandsontable in R Shiny to display an interactive table and as a user input for selecting rows.  Given there are a few packages for doing this in R, I thought there would be even more libraries in python for selecting rows from an interactive table - however I haven't found one yet.  Please let me know if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also love the way Datatable works for shiny R, and have been searching for an equivalent in shiny Python.
The latest release of shiny Python (0.4) has a new feature "data grid / data table" that looks promising !
Here are the links to the release announcement and the API documentation:

https://shiny.posit.co/blog/posts/shiny-python-0.4.0/

https://shiny.posit.co/py/api/render.DataTable.html

They show an example of getting the selected rows in a callback (as you asked)

Hope this helps