# Is there a table widget for Shiny for python that calls back edited cells?

Tags: python, py-shiny

Similar question to [Is there an interactive table widget for Shiny for python that calls back selected rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579007/is-there-an-interactive-table-widget-for-shiny-for-python-that-calls-back-select), but slightly different: Instead of just selecting rows (and getting the information about which row is selected), I want to edit cells in the displayed table and get back the edited table in a callback.

On https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/ipywidgets.html, there are three ipywidgets libraries mentioned. I tried for example with [ipyregulartable](https://github.com/finos/ipyregulartable/tree/main), this example should be runnable:

```
from shiny import ui, render, App, reactive
import ipyregulartable as rt
import pandas as pd
from shinywidgets import output_widget, reactive_read, register_widget

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.panel_sidebar(),
        ui.panel_main(
            output_widget("table"),
            ui.output_table("changed_table"),
        ),
    )
)


def server(input, output, session):
    dummy = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "title": ["A", "B", "C"],
            "img_name": ["food.png", "food2.jpg", "food3.jpg"],
        }
    )
    tbl = rt.RegularTableWidget(dummy)
    tbl.editable(0, 100) # don't know if necessary
    register_widget("table", tbl)

    @output
    @render.table
    def changed_table():
        changed = reactive_read(tbl, "datamodel")
        return pd.DataFrame(changed._data)


app = App(app_ui, server)
```

The dummy data is both displayed as a widget and the data received by the `reactive_read()` is displayed as well. However, when I edit the table, the changes are not reflected in the attribute "datamodel" which is caught by `reactive_read`.

Does anybody know how to catch the changes with ipyregulartable? Or any other possibility to have an interactive table in shiny/python with a callback for cell edits? Similar question was also posted [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/will-shiny-for-python-have-editable-datatables/171417).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution how to catch table changes, by using the package `ipydatagrid`. The following was helpful: https://github.com/bloomberg/ipydatagrid/blob/main/examples/CellEditing.ipynb

```
from shiny import ui, render, App, reactive
from ipydatagrid import DataGrid
import pandas as pd
from shinywidgets import output_widget, register_widget

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.panel_sidebar(),
        ui.panel_main(
            output_widget("table"),
        ),
    )
)


def server(input, output, session):
    dummy = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "title": ["A", "B", "C"],
            "img_name": ["food.png", "food2.jpg", "food3.jpg"],
        }
    )
    tbl = DataGrid(dummy, editable=True)
    register_widget("table", tbl)

    # Create a reactive value for tracking cell changes
    cell_changes = reactive.Value()

    def on_cell_changed(cell):
        cell_changes.set(str(cell))

    # register callback
    tbl.on_cell_change(on_cell_changed)

    # Print change, just to demonstrate
    @reactive.Effect
    def print_change():
        print(eval(cell_changes()))


app = App(app_ui, server)
```

The reactive value `cell_changes()` could be used to change the table `dummy` and to redisplay it by means of an `@output`.